# export server log file from event viewer and save into a folder without overwrite the file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, overwrite, file-rename

I want to export server log file from event viewer and save into a folder without overwrite the file.

Then I will set a schedule by using task schedule to trigger this batch file for automatic periodic update. (I am new in `wevtuitil` and `cmd` command)

Example:

```
application_event1.evtx
application_event2.evtx
application_event3.evtx
application_event4.evtx
```

Here is my script for bat file

> //I will export the log file from event viewer

```
wevtutil epl Application E:\a\testing_application.evtx
```

Follow by script to make the evtx file name increase number

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=E:\a"
if exist "%source%\*.evtx" (
set  increase=0
set  increase=!increase!+1
ren "%source%\*.evtx" "*.!increase!.evtx"
)
endlocal
```

> result: testing_application.0+1,testing_application.0+1.0+1

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? If so, tell us how in a post and approve it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `/a` in `set` because it's arithmetic operation. For more type `set /?`

Also you are missing `for-loop` too. for more type `for /?`

<s>Try something like this.</s>

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=E:\a"

set increase=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.evtx"') do (
    set /a increase+=1
    echo ren "%%~a" "%%~na!increase!%%~xa"
)
endlocal
```

I seem to be completely wrong in what I thought you were trying to achieve.

Here another attempt:

```
@echo off

set "source=E:\a"
set "filename=testing_application"
wevtutil epl Application E:\a\testing_application.evtx

for /f "tokens=2 delims=-." %%a in (
  'dir /b "%source%\%filename%*.evtx" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]') do ( 
   set "num=%%a"
   goto done
)

ren "%source%\%filename%.evtx"  "%filename%-001.evtx"
exit /b 0

:done
rem :: remove zeros in front of numbers before incrementing
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in ("%num%") do set num=%%a

set /a num+=1
set incr=000%num%

ren "%source%\%filename%.evtx"  "%filename%-%incr:~-3%.evtx"

exit /b 0
```

The solution found for incrementing number with zeros in front are based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876832)

Which zeros in front are required to `sort` the files correctly.

Comment: Actually  
wevtutil epl Application E:\a\testing_application.evtx  
this script also have problem. Yes, it allow me to extract the file from event viewer but if the folder is containing a same name with the testing_application.evtx then the script will not working.

Comment: after remove the echo in front of ren command, the error I get is "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: what do you think? This way is working or you have another way which is more less step compare with my way?

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thank you

Comment: i follow exactly the script with two folder call bar and foo. I demo-000.txt in bar folder and foo folder and the bat file at bar folder. When I run it is show me the list directory of the bar folder and the highest number found is 1 -1. "The system cannot find the file specified"