# Increment a number with leading zeros by a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Getting trouble for incrementing number with zeros in front.

It fail after 0008 telling me `filename already exist or file not found`.
Very odd.

Here is the script:

```vb
@echo off

copy nul %tmp%\filename.tmp

for /f "tokens=2 delims=-." %%a in (
   'dir /b "%tmp%\filename*.tmp" ^|sort /r ^|findstr /r [0-9]'
) do (
      set "num=%%a"
      goto :done
)

ren %tmp%\filename.tmp  filename-0001.tmp
exit /b 0

:done
echo the highest number found is %num%
set /a num+=1
set incr=0000%num%

ren %tmp%\filename.tmp  filename-%incr:~-4%.tmp

dir /b "%tmp%\filename*.tmp" |sort /r
```

Thus simplifying the problem:

```vb
@echo off

set "num=008"
echo num: %num%
set /a num=num+1
echo num: %num%

echo let's try another syntax
set "num=008"
echo num: %num%
set /a num+=1
echo num: %num%
```

output:

```vb
num: 008
num: 1
let's try another syntax
num: 008
num: 1
```

Comment: It's because numbers with leading zeros are interpreted as octal numbers; this is true for `set /A` and `if` for numeric comparisons;

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to add a preceding 1 (so that it's not interpreted as an octal), then increment, then trim away the 1.

The largest number is limited by CMD's set /a command.

```
@echo off
set "num=008"
echo num: %num%
set "num=1%num%"
echo num: %num%
set /a num=num+1
echo num: %num%
set  num=%num:~1%
echo num: %num%
pause
```

Comment: The only required parts being: `set num=1%num%`, `set /a num=num+1`, `set num=%num:~1%`

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found is to [remove zeros](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_leadingzero.php) in front before incrementing.

Like:

```
set "num=008"
echo num: %num%

for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in ("%num%") do set num=%%a

set /a num+=1
echo num: %num%
```

Comment: This will clear `num` if it was `0` originally, as `%%a` is empty then; although incrementing `+=` will not fail in such a case...

Answer (score 2):

It's because numbers with leading zeros are interpreted as octal numbers. `8` and `9` are not valid octal digits.
This is true for `set /A` and `if` for numeric comparisons (type `set /?` and `if /?`).

There are ways to handle such numbers correctly as decimal values:

- To do numeric operations you need to remove the leading zeros like already described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876832/5047996) here.
- Alternatively you could prepend a `1` for some operations; for instance, to compare `if 1%A% gtr 1%B%`, in case both `%A%` and `%B%` consist of the same number of digits.
- Another option is to add a great number plus the increment value and subtract just the great number later; for example, you have `var=007` to increment, so do `set /A var+=(100+1)`, then do `set /A var-=100`, to get `var+1` (`8`). (Note that the great number `100` must consist of at least as much digits as the value to increment.)
- Finally, you can use the modulo operator; for instance, you want to increment `var=007`, you can do `set var=1%var%` to get `1007`, then do `set /A var=(var+1)%%1000` to increment and remove the `1`, so to get `8`.

**Note:** Numbers starting with `0x` are hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Yes, I realize it later with the simplified example. You know a way without removing zeros?

Comment: Removing zeros seems much simpler.

Comment: I just added another option that is a bit more obvious than prepending a digit `1`: intermittent addition of a huge number...

Comment: I see, similar to the way with modulo `SET /A Var = 100%Var% %% 100`